# Output log file banner once when running tests in parallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing, cucumber, log4j2, maven-surefire-plugin

The project uses Java, Selenium, Cucumber, Log4j2 and the Maven Surefire plugin.

I have a log banner that I'd like to have at the top my logfile. However, the tests are running in parallel. How can I make the log banner be output only once?

I've been searching for banner, but that doesn't give me a lot of results. Searching for header gives me the "wrong" results.

UPDATE:

This seems to work. I added `volatile` first, but sometimes, I got two banners printed intertwined (still better than how it was earlier). When I added `synchronized` it seems to do what I want. I have no clue if this is the correct way of even using those keywords, or if it's a fluke.

Hope this helps someone, else, I'm ready to be educated.

```java
class Foo() {
  private static volatile Boolean isDone = false;

  public Foo() {

    [...]
  
    if (!isDone) {
      isDone = true;
      doOnlyOnce();
    }
  }

  synchronized private void doOnlyOnce() {
    [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: You should consider reading the [Java Tutorial on Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Comment: I did, that's where I found those keywords. Saying I understand what I read is a huge stretch, though. Noone to ask at work, so I'm on my own.